# MS Access Database Design - User Input Comparison

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, database-design, webforms, mapping

I have a user input form (asp.net) where user rates each question on a scale of 1 to 5 and is given some recommendations for each question depending on his input. Questions and their recommendations are totally independent of each other and for every rating of an question there is a particular recommendation to be displayed.  Could someone help me out with the database design for this and how to achieve this?
Something like this.

EDIT:
My recommendations are based on user input and there is a unique recommendation for each user input. I mean if there are 5 questions on a scale of 5, then i have in all 25 recommendations.

```
    1           2            3              4              5
Question1    Recom.1     Recom.2      Recom3         Recom4         Recom5
Question2    Recom6      Recom7       Recom8         Recom9         Recom10
Question3 ................................................................
```

Comment: Are you providing the user with the recommendations or the other way around?

Comment: Yeah i m providing the user a recommendation based on his input.

Comment: I m not sure if it helps this question but on what criteria are the recommendations displayed ? I.e. Are they fixed, like if a Qn is rated 1 then display recommendation 5 or do you have something else going on , if so edit your question to explain?

Comment: Hey, I have added some more detail to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assist you with the design part of the question

Build tables based on something like this

[image]

From what I've gathered from the question,

`Recommendations` are independent of Questions ,since there is no activity related to them, i.e. the user isn't doing anything with the recommendations except viewing them

You will populate the form with the `Questions` and collect the ratings into `QuestionRatings` Table 
Recommendations are just there to display them

You will have to use some code in your form to display `Recommendations` based on rating

Comment: Thank you sir. The database structure is now pretty clear to me.The problem is I m using an MS-Access database in my project and that doesnt allow multiple tables to be accesses simultaneously (unless you have a uniform table structure). Any idea how to implement this?